# How handle a global variable which has changable value in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, global-variables

Suppose we have a variable which must be accessible from all over the laravel app.
This variable can be changed by end user.

First I thought it can be defined as a key in one of config files in `config` directory of laravel and whenever the user change the value of this variable, we can use `config::set` helper somehow to update the value of this variable in config file.

But the problem is that all config files will be cached in laravel and `config::set` does not do the job.

I prefer to not use database storage approach.

Any suggestion for solving such a problem?

Thanks in advance,